# Adding custom constraint to a GeoDjango table?

Tags: sql, geodjango, validation

I wish to add a custom constraint to a GeoDjango table.

This is the corresponding sql-statement:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
   ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_valid_geom CHECK (ST_IsValid(geom));
```

Do I really have to inject the sql directly?

That seems like a frequently occurring constraint to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the constraint in a migration.
Or, in something more pretty: a custom field